# spring security loadUserByUsername username empty after login url is not used for a few days

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(cUserDetailService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .failureHandler(failureHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false);
}


public class CUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDetailDataEntityRepository userDetailDataEntityRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    log.info("username: " + username + ", " );
    log.info(username == null);

    Optional<UserDetailDataEntity> optional = userDetailDataEntityRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        return optional.get();
    } else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
}
```

}
I used this config for my spring security, and got success login at first.
but then we find that if nobody access the server(even the login url) for a few days, and do login again the loadUserByUsername username will be empty and get login fail

FYI I used redis for session manage by adding dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and the login request is a form request

Comment: Show your  configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) method and your custom userdetialService. BTW, I did not see your sessionRegisty which replaces the in memory session with redis. I wonder if your session stores in your redis

Comment: lol, I just found your name looks like Chinese. If so ,it is what you need  https://blog.csdn.net/yuanlaijike/article/details/84638745

Comment: @wl.GIG thanks for the blog, I'm sure session is stored in redis, and I can success login at first time, but the problem is log info username is empty

Comment: did you check your frontend input label?  the name field needs to match the .usernameParameter("username")

Comment: @wl.GIG yes, I used post man to send the request, and after I restart the server I can success login use the same request